# How to avoid refreshing all p:tabs in a p:tabview, is there any way to clear the cache and set dynamic true for only specific tabs?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am using JSF 2.0 with PrimeFaces 5.0, I have three tabs in my application, the first tab is the master and the remaining two tabs are details which are based on the row selection from master. The problem is that when I set `dynamic="true"` and `cache="false"` then all the tabs are refreshing.I want to keep the cache for the master and just only refresh the details(other two tabs)

```
   <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    template="/WEB-INF/template/master.xhtml">


    <ui:define name="title">
        #{loc.Clients_Title_Name_Index}                                                                        
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="head">



    <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form id="stepsForm">
            <p:steps  
                activeIndex="#{retClientsBean.activeTabIndex}"  styleClass="custom" >
                <p:menuitem value="Ret Clients"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Ret Accounts"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Ret Contracts"/>

            </p:steps>

        </h:form>

        <h:form>
            <p:remoteCommand name="updateListForm"
                update="tabs:RetAccountsForm  tabs:RetContractsForm"></p:remoteCommand>
        </h:form>

        <p:tabView id="tabs"  dynamic="true" cache="false">
            <p:ajax event="tabChange" update=":stepsForm" 
                listener="#{retClientsBean.onTabChange}" />

            <p:tab id="ClientsListTab" 
                title="Ret Clients">

                   <ui:include src="ClientsList.xhtml"/>

                   <ui:include src="EditClientsDialog.xhtml"/>

                  <ui:include src="CreateClientsDialog.xhtml"/>
            </p:tab>



            <p:tab id="RetAccountsTab" title="Ret Accounts">



                <ui:include src="/Admin/RetAccounts/List.xhtml" />
                <ui:include src="/Admin/RetSituationsAccount/RetSituationsAccountList.xhtml"/>
                <ui:include src="/Admin/RetLimitsAccounts/RetLimitsAccountsList.xhtml"/>
                <ui:include src="/Admin/RetCards/RetCardsList.xhtml"/>

            </p:tab>


            <p:tab id="RetContractsTab"  
                title="Ret Contracts">

                <ui:include src="/Admin/RetContracts/List.xhtml" />
               <ui:include src="/Admin/RetInstallmentsContract/RetInstallmentsContractList.xhtml" />


            </p:tab>

        </p:tabView>


    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

[Click here to see the application View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IsdY.jpg)

Comment: Not possible directly in PF 5.0 (nor in the latest 5.3 afaik). And I don't have the time now to think of a possible workaround, sorry. Best bet for now is to download the source of PF, look at how the caching and/or dynamic features are implemented and create a 'patch'

Comment: @Kukeltje thnx bro !

Comment: @Kukeltje i am sorry Sir but just guide me a little if i want to clear the cache inside backing bean on bases of tab-id during TabChangeEvent  so would you prefer that ?

Comment: I don't have a ready of the shelf solution, so the only way I could guide you is be starting to investigate the source and think of a way to solve it. Since this is not a simple one line solution (or a little more complex that I can do from the top of my head), it goes beyond the time I want to invest in writing answers. For now at least.